# Unity Sprite two images animation at runtime

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am creating a gameObject from an image("Resources/dog") by this:

```
tex = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("dog") as Texture2D;
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 250, 150), new Vector2(Random.Range(-1.5f, 1.5f), Random.Range(-1.5f, 1.5f)));
GameObject newSprite = new GameObject();
newSprite.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
newSprite.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;    
newSprite.AddComponent<ObjectMovement>();
newSprite.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();  
SR = newSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
SR.sprite = sprite;
```

I have another image("Resources/dog1") and I want to create an animation switching the images, I can create another sprite for the other image and switch between them every time `update()` is called but is it the best way? it will take a lot of memory.

Also, if you drag two images to the scene it creates an animated sprite, I think attaching the animation will be better then switching sprites every update for every gameobject I have(max 10).
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Only two two images or more? Also where is the animation code? This is not complete.

Comment: @Programmer Only two, but I have 10 objects, some are pigs some are dogs etc.. each object has two images to animate while idling..

Comment: Ok. How many seconds do you switch each two sprites?

Comment: @Programmer I just want it to look animated, I guess 0.5sec is fine, it's just a dog waving his tail..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the Animator in Unity but doing with code gives you more control. Coroutines is one of the best ways to do this.

**1**.Create a script called `SpriteAnimator`. Copy everything from below to it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpriteAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool continueAnimation = false;

    SpriteRenderer displaySprite;
    Sprite sprite1;
    Sprite sprite2;

    public void setupSprites(SpriteRenderer displaySprite, string animSprite1, string animSprite2)
    {
        //Set where the animated sprite will be updated
        this.displaySprite = displaySprite;

        //Load Sprite 1
        Texture2D tex = Resources.Load<Texture2D>(animSprite1) as Texture2D;
        sprite1 = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 250, 150), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 40);

        //Load Sprite 2
        Texture2D tex2 = Resources.Load<Texture2D>(animSprite2) as Texture2D;
        sprite2 = Sprite.Create(tex2, new Rect(0, 0, 250, 150), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 40);
    }

    private IEnumerator startAnimationCRT(float time)
    {
        if (continueAnimation)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        continueAnimation = true;

        WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(time);
        while (continueAnimation)
        {
            //Change to Sprite1
            displaySprite.sprite = sprite1;

            //Wait for `time` amount
            yield return waitTime;

            //Change Sprite
            displaySprite.sprite = sprite2;

            //Wait for `time` amount
            yield return waitTime;
        }

        continueAnimation = false;
    }

    public void startAnimation(float time)
    {
        StartCoroutine(startAnimationCRT(time));
    }

    public void stopAnimation()
    {
        continueAnimation = false;
    }

    public void removeAnimation()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

**2**.Create another script called `SpriteAnimation`. Copy everything from below to it. Also remove "`: MonoBehaviour`" after the class name. **You must do this!** It can't derive from `MonoBehaviour` so remove it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpriteAnimation
{
    SpriteAnimator spriteAnimator;
    GameObject gameObj;

    public void setupSprites(string animationName, SpriteRenderer displaySprite, string animSprite1, string animSprite2)
    {
        gameObj = new GameObject(animationName);
        gameObj.AddComponent<SpriteAnimator>();
        spriteAnimator = gameObj.GetComponent<SpriteAnimator>();
        spriteAnimator.setupSprites(displaySprite, animSprite1, animSprite2);
    }

    public void startAnimation(float time = 0.5f)
    {
        spriteAnimator.startAnimation(time);
    }

    public void stopAnimation()
    {
        spriteAnimator.stopAnimation();
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        spriteAnimator.removeAnimation();
    }
}
```

Done. How to use:

```
public SpriteRenderer SR;
SpriteAnimation dogAnimation;

void Start()
{
    dogAnimation = new SpriteAnimation();
    dogAnimation.setupSprites("DogAnimation", SR, "dog", "dog2");
    dogAnimation.startAnimation(0.2f);
}
```

Call `dogAnimation.stopAnimation();` to stop the animation.
You can create many `SpriteAnimations` as you want. The line of code `dogAnimation.setupSprites("DogAnimation", SR, "dog", "dog2");` will setup animation. It will create a new `GameObject` named `DogAnimation`. It will then load two images called `dog` and `dog2` from the `Resources` folder so make sure those exist. `SR` is the texture on the screen that will be changed with `dog2` and `dog` images. `dogAnimation.startAnimation(0.2f);` will start the animation and you can pass in the animation transition time inside.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 Np. You can also modify it to take arrays. That will let it work with any amount of sprite animation. Don't forget to remove the line `Vector2(Random.Range(-1.5f, 1.5f), Random.Range(-1.5f, 1.5f))` from your code. You had that in your question and I asked you to remove it. It will cost problems later on for you as the image won't appear on screen with that sometimes.

Comment: I already removed it, I think I copied this code from the previous thread so it's not updated or something. Thanks :)

Comment: I have created a different classed, and sent a RaycastHit2D from it, then when I hit a gameObject I got it by using hit.transform.gameObject , I want to stop the animation for this particular gameObject how can I call stopAnimation from a different class?

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 This means that you have to create a script for each GameObject. Let's say the script name is`AnimHolder`. Declare `SpriteAnimation` inside that script and make it public so that you can `getComponent<AnimHolder>().SpriteAnimationInstance` on it and be able to call `startAnimation` and `stopAnimation`. Ask a new question then link it here if you are still confused.

Comment: Great, also you forgot to mention I need to call newSprite.getComponent<AnimHolder>().SpriteAnimationInstance = dogAnimation; 
Thanks :)

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 Anything that works for you is fine. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

No need to make animation switching between sprites. Use Animator component - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html

See this tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/player-and-enemy-animations

Comment: I am doing this at runtime, I tried adding the animator by this line:
newSprite.addComponent<Animator>(); 
but how do I make the Animator play the animation I want for this specific gameObject?

Comment: You can store different animations in AnimationClip objects and pass them to animation.Play() method: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.html